# How to check if list contains a String, but String value is from other dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

As you can see I have a list:

```
  List avatarList = [
    AssetsResources.VIP1,
    AssetsResources.VIP2,
    AssetsResources.VIP3,
    AssetsResources.VIP4,
    AssetsResources.VIP5,
    AssetsResources.w1,
    AssetsResources.w2,
  ];
```

I understand I can use method:

```
final bool isVIP = avatarList[index].contains('VIP');
```

But since `AssetsResources.VIP1` is not a String like `'VIP1'`but a path from other dart file, so here I have no idea how to check if the element from avatarList contains VIP value, thanks for any clue!

***Update***

Thanks guys for the help and sorry I didnt describe clearly, what I mean is, if

```
  List idealList = [
    'vip1',
    'vip2',
    'vip3',
    'vip4',
    'vip5',
  ];
```

so the elements in the idealList is `'vip1'` but in my case the list myList is

```
  List myList = [
    AssetsResources.VIP1,
    AssetsResources.VIP2,
    AssetsResources.VIP3,
    AssetsResources.VIP4,
    AssetsResources.VIP5,
    AssetsResources.w1,
    AssetsResources.w2,
  ];
```

So it seems I can not directly use some methode as follows

```
final bool isVIP = myList[index].contains('VIP');
```

since the elements from myList is just a path(sorry I dont know how to call this value), could you please let me know in my case how to check if this path contains `'VIP'` value? thanks!

**Update**
yes, AssetsResources is very simple, just store the asset path:

```
class AssetsResources {
  /*worm avatar*/
  static const String VIP1 = 'assets/worms/VIP_1.svg';
  static const String VIP2 = 'assets/worms/VIP_2.svg';
  static const String VIP3 = 'assets/worms/VIP_3.svg';
  static const String VIP4 = 'assets/worms/VIP_4.svg';

}
```

Comment: You want to check if `VIP1` is present in the path name itself ?

Comment: hi esentis, plz check my update, thanks:)

Comment: What does `print(myList[0])` prints exactly ?

Comment: I think the output will be AssetsResources.VIP1, but what I expected should be like 'AssetsResources.VIP1' right? So should I transfer firstly the value into '***'?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the `AssetsResources` implementation ?

Comment: yeah plz check my update. thx:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should work fine :

```dart
class AssetsResources {
  /*worm avatar*/
  static const String VIP1 = 'assets/worms/VIP_1.svg';
  static const String VIP2 = 'assets/worms/VIP_2.svg';
  static const String VIP3 = 'assets/worms/VIP_3.svg';
  static const String VIP4 = 'assets/worms/VIP_4.svg';
}

void main() {
  List myList = [
    AssetsResources.VIP1,
    AssetsResources.VIP2,
    AssetsResources.VIP3,
    AssetsResources.VIP4,
  ];

  for (final asset in myList) {
    print(asset);
    print(asset.contains('VIP'));
  }
}
```

The above prints :

```
assets/worms/VIP_1.svg
true
assets/worms/VIP_2.svg
true
assets/worms/VIP_3.svg
true
assets/worms/VIP_4.svg
true
```

Comment: Hi esentis, thank you a lot for your patient explanation, it indeeds works:)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly.

```dart
void main() {
  for(var i = 0; i < avatarList.length; i++) {
    String element = avatarList[i];
    
    if(element.contains('VIP')) {
      print(other.contains(element)); // true
      print(other.firstWhere((e) => e.contains(element))); // 'VIP1', 'VIP2', 'VIP3', 'VIP4', 'VIP5'
    }
  }
}

List<String> avatarList = ['VIP1', 'VIP2', 'VIP3', 'VIP4', 'VIP5', 'w1', 'w2'];
List<String> other = ['VIP1', 'VIP2', 'VIP3', 'VIP4', 'VIP5', 'w1', 'w2'];
```

Comment: hi Arnas, plz check my update, thanks:)